# Looping for commands

Tags: c

My code is suppose to loop for a command and then execute the command until the command is exit. When it runs I get a never ending loop.

```
void run(){
    char command[100][100], *p;
    int numOfArgs;
    while(1){
        p=&command[0][0];
        numOfArgs = 0;
        while(getchar()!= '\n'){
            while(getchar()!= ' '){
                *p=getchar();
                p++;    //increased to next char in string
            }
            *p='\0';
            numOfArgs++;    //increases number of strings
            p=&command[numOfArgs][0]; //References p to location 0 of next string
        }
        if(strcmp(command[0], "/*command*/") == 0){
            //Do command
        }

        if(strcmp(command[0], "exit") == 0)
            return;

        else printf("Not a valid command");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note: you never look at anything other than `command[0]`, and you never seem to change it either.

Comment: Why are you taking the command character by character rather than using `scanf`?

Comment: &command[0][0] is a pretty weird syntax (though correct). Why don't you use simply command[0] instead?

Answer (score 3):

Change line 13 to

```
p=&command[numOfArgs][0];
```

Also you need to terminate your command with `\0`.

Comment: I believe I have updated the code to add \0 at the end of each word.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem has already been pointed out i.e. no terminating null i.e. "\0". But just elaborating what happens.

Since you are taking input char by char instead of sprintf or gets etc., your command[index] does not terminate with a null.

As there is no terminating null, the strcmp, **never terminates at the right comparison**, but rather *keeps comparing until null is found*. Hence it always results in a mismatch and continues looping.